# how to linux command find many types

Tags: linux, command

my command

```
find / \(-type d -type f\) name
```

but this command return error

> find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

i want only file or directory search

how to many types in linux command find

Comment: The error message is clear. You can only put one letter after `-type`, but you put `f)`, which is two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around the parentheses, since they have to be separate arguments to the `find` command.

The way you wrote it, it thinks that it should start in the directories named `/` and `(-type`, and look for something whose type is `f)`, but that's not a valid type abbreviation.

Also, of you want to search for multiple types, you have to connect them with `-o` for `OR`. The default connector is `AND`, and there are no files that are both ordinary files and directories.

```
find / \( -type d -o -type f \)
```